# Авторизация в Steam на Delphi

Tags: delphi, rsa, steam, cryptoapi

Добрый день, есть желание из своей программы, написанной на Delphi, авторизоваться в Steam.
Посмотрев исходники программы [Steam Desktop Authenticator](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamDesktopAuthenticator), пришел к выводу, что нам нужно сделать 2 POST-запроса к серверу Steam, первый вернет нам модуль и экспоненту открытого ключа RSA, которым мы должны зашифровать свой пароль и отправить его во втором запросе. Решил попробовать реализовать это с помощью функций Microsoft CryptoAPI: Next Generation.
Набросал функцию, которая на входе получает 3 строки: пароль от Стима, открытые модуль и экспоненту в виде строк, состоящих из шестнадцатеричных символов (их нам присылает сервер). На выходе должны получить пароль, зашифрованный открытым ключом по алгоритму RSA и закодированный в BASE64.

```
    unit uRSA;

    interface
    uses WinAPI.Windows, System.SysUtils, VCL.Dialogs, System.NetEncoding;

    //БЛОБ открытого ключа RSA, описание структуры есть на MSDN
    type TPublicKeyBLOB = packed record
    Magic: ULONG;
    BitLength: ULONG;
    cbPublicExp: ULONG;
    cbModulus: ULONG;
    cbPrime1: ULONG;
    cbPrime2: ULONG;
    exponent: array[0..2] of byte;
    modulus: array[0..255] of byte;
    end;
    pPublicKeyBLOB = ^TPublicKeyBLOB;

    //прототипы функций из библиотеки BCRYPT.DLL
    TBCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider = function (phAlgorithm: pHandle; pszAlgId: LPCWSTR;
    pszImplementation: LPCWSTR; dwFlags: DWORD): ULONG; stdcall;
    //--
    TBCryptImportKeyPair = function (hAlgorithm: THandle; hImportKey: THandle; pszBlobType: LPCWSTR;
    phKey: pHandle; pbInput: pPublicKeyBLOB; cbInput: ULONG; dwFlags: ULONG): ULONG; stdcall;
    //--
    TBCryptEncrypt = function (hKey: THandle; pbInput: PUCHAR; cbInput: ULONG; pPaddingInfo: POINTER;
    pbIV: PUCHAR; cbIV: ULONG; pbOutput: PUCHAR; cbOutput: ULONG; pcbResult: PULONG; dwFlags: ULONG): ULONG; stdcall;
    //--
    TBCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider = function (hAlgorithm: THandle; dwFlags: ULONG): ULONG; stdcall;

    //сама функция шифрования
    type TRSA = class
    public
    function RSA_Encrypt(DataStr: string; modulusStr: string; exponentStr:   string): string;
    end;

    const
    BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_MAGIC = $31415352;  // RSA1
    BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1 = $00000002;

    implementation

    function HexToByte(Str: string): Byte;
    begin
    result :=  Byte(StrToInt('$' + (Str)));
    end;

    function TRsa.RSA_Encrypt(DataStr: string; modulusStr: string; exponentStr: string): string;
    var
    PublicKeyBLOB: TPublicKeyBlob;
    i: word;
    status: ULONG;
    hLib: THandle;
    hAlg: THandle;
    hKey: tHandle;
    Password: TBytes;
    EncryptedPassword: TBytes;
    EncryptedSize: ULONG;
    BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider: TBCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider;
    BCryptImportKeyPair: TBCryptImportKeyPair;
    BCryptEncrypt: TBCryptEncrypt;
    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider: TBCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider;
    begin
    //преобразовываем входные данные в массив байтов;
    Password := TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DataStr);
    hLib := LoadLibrary('BCRYPT.DLL');
    //загрузка функций из библиотеки
    //функция инициализации провайдера
    @BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider := GetProcAddress(hLib, 'BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider');
    //функция импорта ключа
    @BCryptImportKeyPair := GetProcAddress(hLib, 'BCryptImportKeyPair');
    //функция шифрования
    @BCryptEncrypt := GetProcAddress(hLib, 'BCryptEncrypt');
    //функция освобождения провайдера
    @BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider := GetProcAddress(hLib, 'BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider');
    //собираем ключ
    with PublicKeyBLOB do
    begin
    Magic := BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_MAGIC;  // RSA1;
    BitLength := SizeOf(Modulus)*8;//размер модуля в битах
    cbPublicExp := SizeOf(Exponent);//размер экспоненты в байтах
    cbModulus := SizeOf(Modulus);//размер модуля в байтах
    //(необязательно) проверим, что в переданных параметрах - четное количество символов
    if (length(exponentstr) mod 2)  0 then
    exponentstr := '0' + exponentstr;
    if (length(modulusstr) mod 2)  0 then
    modulusstr := '0' + modulusstr;
    for i := Low(exponent) to High(exponent) do
    exponent[i] := HexToByte(copy(exponentstr,i*2+1,2));
    for i := Low(modulus) to High(modulus) do
    modulus[i] := HexToByte(copy(modulusstr,i*2+1,2));
    end;
    //инициализация провайдера
    status := BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(@halg,'RSA',nil,0);
    //импорт ключа
    status := BCryptImportKeyPair(hAlg,0,'RSAPUBLICBLOB', @hKey, @PublicKeyBLOB,
    SizeOf(PublicKeyBLOB),0);
    //шифрование сообщения. Первый проход - получаем размер выходного буфера, второй - шифруем текст
    status := BCryptEncrypt(hKey, @Password[0], Length(Password), nil, nil, 0, nil, 0, @EncryptedSize, BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1);
    SetLength(EncryptedPassword,EncryptedSize);
    status := BCryptEncrypt(hKey, @Password[0], Length(Password), nil, nil, 0, @EncryptedPassword[0], Length(EncryptedPassword), @EncryptedSize, BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1);
    //кодируем зашифрованное сообщение в Base64
    Result := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(EncryptedPassword);
    //освобождаем память
    status := BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg,0);
    FreeLibrary(hLib);
    end;

    end.
```

Вроде бы все успешно отрабатывает, но, когда делаю POST-запрос с зашифрованным паролем к серверу STEAM - получаю в ответ:

```
    {"success":false,"requires_twofactor":false,
   "message":"The account name or password that you have entered is incorrect.",
   "clear_password_field":true,"captcha_needed":false,"captcha_gid":-1}
```

На вход функции подаются строки в виде

```
   "publickey_mod":"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",
   "publickey_exp":"010001"
```

Буду очень признателен, если кто-нибудь укажет на ошибку или даст совет: как в Delphi можно зашифровать сообщение, имея экспоненту и модуль открытого ключа RSA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема была в некорректной работе

```
//кодируем зашифрованное сообщение в Base64
Result := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(EncryptedPassword);
```

Эта функция не убирает переносы строки, так что придется получившийся результат обработать дополнительно:

```
//кодируем зашифрованное сообщение в Base64
Result := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(EncryptedPassword);
//удалим переносы строки
Result := StringReplace(Result, #13#10, '',[rfReplaceAll]);
```

Либо же можно использовать аналогичную функцию из пакета Indy, которая работает верно:

```
uses IdCoderMIME, idcoder, idglobal;
...
function MyFunc(): string;
var
Temp: TIdBytes;
begin
...
Result := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeBytes(Temp);
end;
```

---

Рабочий код :

```
unit uRSA;

interface
uses WinAPI.Windows, System.SysUtils, VCL.Dialogs, System.NetEncoding;

//БЛОБ открытого ключа RSA, описание структуры есть на MSDN
type TPublicKeyBLOB = packed record
Magic: ULONG;
BitLength: ULONG;
cbPublicExp: ULONG;
cbModulus: ULONG;
cbPrime1: ULONG;
cbPrime2: ULONG;
exponent: array[0..2] of byte;
modulus: array[0..255] of byte;
end;
pPublicKeyBLOB = ^TPublicKeyBLOB;

//прототипы функций из библиотеки BCRYPT.DLL
TBCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider = function (phAlgorithm: pHandle; pszAlgId: LPCWSTR;
pszImplementation: LPCWSTR; dwFlags: DWORD): ULONG; stdcall;
//--
TBCryptImportKeyPair = function (hAlgorithm: THandle; hImportKey: THandle; pszBlobType: LPCWSTR;
phKey: pHandle; pbInput: pPublicKeyBLOB; cbInput: ULONG; dwFlags: ULONG): ULONG; stdcall;
//--
TBCryptEncrypt = function (hKey: THandle; pbInput: PUCHAR; cbInput: ULONG; pPaddingInfo: POINTER;
pbIV: PUCHAR; cbIV: ULONG; pbOutput: PUCHAR; cbOutput: ULONG; pcbResult: PULONG; dwFlags: ULONG): ULONG; stdcall;
//--
TBCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider = function (hAlgorithm: THandle; dwFlags: ULONG): ULONG; stdcall;

//сама функция шифрования
type TRSA = class
public
function Encrypt(DataStr: string; modulusStr: string; exponentStr:   string): string;
end;

const
BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_MAGIC = $31415352;  // RSA1
BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1 = $00000002;
BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM = 'RSA';
BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB = 'RSAPUBLICBLOB';

implementation

function HexToByte(Str: string): Byte;
begin
result :=  Byte(StrToInt('$' + (Str)));
end;

function TRsa.Encrypt(DataStr: string; modulusStr: string; exponentStr: string): string;
var
PublicKeyBLOB: TPublicKeyBlob;
i: word;
status: ULONG;
hLib: THandle;
hAlg: THandle;
hKey: tHandle;
Password: TBytes;
EncryptedPassword: TBytes;
EncryptedSize: ULONG;
BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider: TBCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider;
BCryptImportKeyPair: TBCryptImportKeyPair;
BCryptEncrypt: TBCryptEncrypt;
BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider: TBCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider;
begin
//преобразовываем входные данные в массив байтов;
Password := TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DataStr);
hLib := LoadLibrary('BCRYPT.DLL');
if hLib < 32 then
begin
 ShowMessage('Error while loading BCRYPT.DLL!');
 exit;
end;
//загрузка функций из библиотеки
//функция инициализации провайдера
@BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider := GetProcAddress(hLib, 'BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider');
//функция импорта ключа
@BCryptImportKeyPair := GetProcAddress(hLib, 'BCryptImportKeyPair');
//функция шифрования
@BCryptEncrypt := GetProcAddress(hLib, 'BCryptEncrypt');
//функция освобождения провайдера
@BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider := GetProcAddress(hLib, 'BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider');
//собираем ключ
with PublicKeyBLOB do
begin
Magic := BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_MAGIC;  // RSA1;
BitLength := SizeOf(Modulus)*8;//размер модуля в битах
cbPublicExp := SizeOf(Exponent);//размер экспоненты в байтах
cbModulus := SizeOf(Modulus);//размер модуля в байтах
//(необязательно) проверим, что в переданных параметрах - четное количество символов
if (length(exponentstr) mod 2) <> 0 then
exponentstr := '0' + exponentstr;
if (length(modulusstr) mod 2) <> 0 then
modulusstr := '0' + modulusstr;
for i := Low(exponent) to High(exponent) do
exponent[i] := HexToByte(copy(exponentstr,i*2+1,2));
for i := Low(modulus) to High(modulus) do
modulus[i] := HexToByte(copy(modulusstr,i*2+1,2));
end;
//инициализация провайдера
status := BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(@halg,BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM,nil,0);
if status <> 0 then
begin
ShowMessage('BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider error, status: ' + IntToStr(status)  + ', ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError()));
exit;
end;
//импорт ключа
status := BCryptImportKeyPair(hAlg,0,BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB, @hKey, @PublicKeyBLOB, SizeOf(PublicKeyBLOB),0);
if status <> 0 then
begin
ShowMessage('BCryptImportKeyPair error, status: ' + IntToStr(status) + ', ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError()));
exit;
end;
//шифрование сообщения. Первый проход - получаем размер выходного буфера, второй - шифруем текст
status := BCryptEncrypt(hKey, @Password[0], Length(Password), nil, nil, 0, nil, 0, @EncryptedSize, BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1);
if status <> 0 then
begin
ShowMessage('BCryptEncrypt error 1, status: ' + IntToStr(status) + ', ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError()));
exit;
end;
SetLength(EncryptedPassword,EncryptedSize);
status := BCryptEncrypt(hKey, @Password[0], Length(Password), nil, nil, 0, @EncryptedPassword[0], Length(EncryptedPassword), @EncryptedSize, BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1);
if status <> 0 then
begin
ShowMessage('BCryptEncrypt error 2, status: ' + IntToStr(status) + ', ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError()));
exit;
end;
//освобождаем занятые ресурсы
status := BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg,0);
if status <> 0 then
begin
ShowMessage('BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider error, status: ' + IntToStr(status) + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError()));
exit;
end;
//кодируем зашифрованное сообщение в Base64
Result := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(EncryptedPassword);
//удалим переносы строки
Result := StringReplace(Result, #13#10, '',[rfReplaceAll]);
//выгружаем библиотеку
FreeLibrary(hLib);
end;

end.
```

На вход функции подаются строки в виде:

> "publickey_mod":"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",
>   "publickey_exp":"010001"